# Display a table column on list view

Tags: android

I am implementing a app that gets data from online mysql and store in mysql lite table contains 2 columns

> **notify**
>
> **date**

I want to display notify column in list view and related date column on right side

**what I got so for**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".ListActivity" >

   <ListView
      android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
         R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);

      ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
```

Comment: You have to use parsing to get data from Mysql database and have to implement custom Adapter for Listview with Two textviews.

Comment: yes i parsed the json string and stored in sql lite android database how can i retrive data from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do in This way:

1. **DatabaseHelper.java** Class:  Just Change package name in path and dbname.

   ```
     package Your package name;

    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


   public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

     //The Android's default system path of your application database.
   private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/your package name/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = " your database name";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

      /**
     * Constructor
         * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
        public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

       super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
   }   

          /**
            * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
         * */
          public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

         boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
           //do nothing - database already exist
       //  Toast.makeText(myContext, "already exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else{

               //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
              //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
               this.getReadableDatabase();

       try {

           copyDataBase();

       } catch (IOException e) {

           //throw new Error("Error copying database");

       }
   }

    }

       /**
          * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
      * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
      */
       private boolean checkDataBase(){

       SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

         try{
               String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
          checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
   //  Toast.makeText(myContext, "already exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }catch(SQLiteException e){

       //database does't exist yet.
       //Toast.makeText(myContext, "not already exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   if(checkDB != null){

       checkDB.close();

     }

     return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

      /**
      * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
      * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
      * This is done by transfering bytestream.
      * */
     private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

       //Open your local db as the input stream
       InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
         String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

   //Open the empty db as the output stream
   OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

   //transfer bytes from the Input file to the output file
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int length;
   while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
       myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
   }

   //Close the streams
   myOutput.flush();
   myOutput.close();
   myInput.close();

   }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

   //Open the database
   String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
   myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

   }

    @Override
     public synchronized void close() {

       if(myDataBase != null)
           myDataBase.close();

       super.close();

    }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

   @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }



     // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
     // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
      // to you to create adapters for your views.

    }
   ```

   2. Your **MainActivity.java** : Make select Method to select url from database;

      ```
        public void select()
      {
      //this is select command code
       //--------------------------------------------------
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

        try 
        {
       myDbHelper.createDataBase(); 
       } catch (IOException ioe ) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");


       }
        database = this.openOrCreateDatabase("your database name", MODE_PRIVATE, null); 
        Cursor crs;
        crs= database.rawQuery("select * from tablename ", null);
       while(crs.moveToNext())
       {
         array.add(crs.getString(index of column));
        // example  : array.add(crs.getString(1));
         level = crs.getInt(4);
         System.out.println("=="+level);

            }
      crs.close();
      database.close();
      }
      ```

Now call Select Method in oncreate and set List adapter;

```
           Select();
          list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getapplicationContext,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array));
```

This is all to select data from database.
Hope this will help you.